# How can i typecast a varchar to float for using aggregate sum() function with group by

Tags: sql

I have a table called `Fare`:

```
CREATE TABLE Fare
(
     Date DATE NOT NULL,
     CardFare VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
     FullFare VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
)
```

I have to group by date and sum cardfare and fullfare but they are of type `varchar` and have $ sign in front of them.

This is the result from running: `Select * from Fare`

[image]

Comment: Do not store numbers in `varchar` columns. If you need to keep the currency information create a numeric column with the fare and another one indicating the currency. If everything you store is in dollars, then just don't store the `$` sign at all

Comment: so, is it better to use double and remove the $ sign?

Comment: I would **strongly** recommend against `double` - it's prone to rounding error etc. If you need to have precise fractional numbers - especially when it comes to money - use `decimal(p,s)` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below - using replace() and cast()

```
select 
    date,
    sum(cast(replace(cardfare,'$','') as decimal(16,2))) as totalcardfare,
    sum(cast(replace(fullfare,'$','') as decimal(16,2))) as totalfullfare
from fare
group by date
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're on SQL Server. I suggest you to use

[**`FORMAT(fare, 'C', 'en-us')`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

to format your strings as currency

```
select sum(FORMAT(card_fare, 'C', 'en-us')) as total_card_fare
from Fare
```

Comment: Actually 7 years is quite a while. : Format is present since MSSQL 2012.